# How to run several code before import syntax in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, import, module

I want to run several code before the code inside `import` syntax gets executed.

**Example**

**`file-1.js`**

```js
console.log('Inside File 1')

import './file-2.js'
```

**`file-2.js`**

```js
console.log('Inside File 2')
```

---

**Output**

```sh
Inside File 2
Inside File 1
```

---

**The output I expected**

```sh
Inside File 1
Inside File 2
```

---

**Environment**

Node JS `v12.19.0` with [Module configuration](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_determining_module_system)

---

**Real Case**

**file-1.js**

```js
process.env.SHARED_DATA = 'Hello world'

import './file-2.js'
```

**file-2.js**

```js
console.log(process.env.SHARED_DATA)
```

**Output**

```sh
undefined
```

Comment: The way import is implemented forbids such actions. Effectively import happens before anything else happens and then when imports are completed then code is executed normaly

Comment: It's hard to judge without a more real example, but you can do `import "log-inside-file1.js"; import "file-2.js"; since the imports themselves will run in order. It can't be anything in the same file though.

Comment: In your real case example, you could export from `file-2.js` only a function.  Then, you import that function (but no code has run yet) and then after setting up the environment, you call the function you imported and file-2.js finishes initializing itself.  Or, you just pass the relevant info directly to the function when you call it rather than setting it into the environment.  In either case, `file-1.js` gets to run code before it calls the `file-2.js` initialization function.  This is a design pattern often called "module constructor" and is used to pass initialization parameters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define the env data in separate file. The `import` syntax will run in the order against the other imports as [@loganfsmyth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785065/loganfsmyth) says.

**Example**

`main.js`

```js
console.log('Inside main.js file')

import './set-env.js'
import './file.js'
```

`set-env.js`

```js
console.log('Inside set-env.js file')

process.env.SHARED_DATA = 'Hello world'
```

`file.js`

```js
console.log(process.env.SHARED_DATA)
```

---

**Output**

```sh
Inside set-env.js file
Hello world
Inside main.js file
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way I find is to use top-level await with [dynamic import](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es-next/javascript-import/).

```
process.env.SHARED_DATA = 'Hello world';
await import('../index.js');
```

Answer (score -3):

In JavaScript the lines don't necesarily wait for the line before to end. One way to solve this issue of yours is to put the file-1.js into a async function:

```
 async function f() {
process.env.SHARED_DATA = "Hello world";
return Promise.resolve(1);
}

f().then(() => {import "./file-2.js"});
```

By calling this function you can make sure the import waits for the f function to end! Then running the arrow function. Hope this helped if you want to read more about this topic here you go. https://javascript.info/async-await